# How to fetch a managed object related to other not using id fields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios7

I have two entities in Core Data model: `User` with attributes name, surname, age, etc. and `UserPicture` with attributes pictureName, binaryData, extension. I also have a relationship `picture` between User and UserPicture entities. I want to select UserPicture with `NSFetchRequest` which is connected to specific user object fetched by me some time before. The problem I don't want to create id fields for the User object. So I can't write `NSPredicate` like this: `"User.id == %@"`. Can I in some way fetch UserPicture object using User `managed object  id` which core data underhood assigns to every object saved? Or fetch only by relationship name? In the ideal case I want this: I fetch `User` object from the store sme time and then I want to fetch UserPicture object which is connected to THIS fetched user object .How can I do this?
P.S. Her is data model:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just fetch by the relationship from `UserPicture` to `User`:

```
User *theUser = ...; // your User object
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user == %@", theUser];
```

This assumes that "user" is a to-one relationship.
For a to-many relationship, you would do

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY user == %@", theUser];
```

Comment: "user == %@". Can you please tell why user is small case?My Entity in Core Data is called User.

Comment: @Harry: You have to use the *relationship* from UserPicture to User. Relationships are usually in lowercase characters.

Comment: I tried this but fetch request fetched nothing at all but I have one userpic in database.Generated SQL statement in debug console was:`SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDATA, t0.ZEXTENSION, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPICTURE FROM ZUSERPICTURE t0 WHERE  t0.ZPICTURE = ? ORDER BY t0.ZNAME DESC`

Comment: picture relationship is inverse by the way

Comment: @Harry: It seems that you used the relationship from User to UserPicture. There should be an inverse relationship from UserPicture to User. (Perhaps you can add a screenshot of your Core Data model to the question.)

Comment: I edited the question.And I told about this in previous "comment:picture relationship is inverse by the way".For both managed objects:User and UserPicture I made `[objectContext insertnewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserPicture"]` and `[objectContext insertnewObjectForEntityForName:@"User"]`

Comment: @Harry: OK. (Note that usually the relationship User->UserPicture would be called "picture" and the inverse relationship UserPicture->User would be called "user". Using the same name for both directions is a bit strange, but it should not cause problems.)

Comment: But how can I make it related to the User?

Comment: May be I must insert it in database some other way?It seems a simple task but I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: @Harry: The insert looks OK. But you have to connect the objects. Have a look at Duncan's answer where he shows how that is done!

Comment: Thanks.But in Duncan answer I don't understand this:
`user.picture = userPicture;` My user object doesn't have any property picture at all. Can you please explain this in order I can accept your answer - you already helped me a lot

Comment: @Harry: According to your screenshot, User *has* a picture property. Did you generate "NSManagedObject subclasses" in Xcode so that you have a User class and a UserPicture class and can use the property accessors? --- This should work in any case: `[user setValue:userPicture forKey:@"picture"]`

Comment: generate "NSManagedObject subclasses" - no I didn't. I just create NSManagedObjects User and UserPicture manually. And User doesn't have a picture property

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Core Data so I don't understand this. Every entity which has a relationship must have a property with relationship name or what?

Comment: @Harry: In your screenshot there is a "picture" relationship at the bottom of the "User" entity. When you create the NSManagedObject subclasses, there should be a corresponding "picture" property in User.h.

Comment: The problem was - I didn't connect those objects.And I really didn't know Xcode can generate managed object subclasses.Can you please give some links. Where said I should connect objects in this way: `user.picture = picture`?Because tutorials I found told about easy and obvious things found in docs. But these details about relationships I didn't know

Comment: @Harry: The Ray Wenderlich tutorials are often recommended. This one covers relationships: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates. I am sure that there are more good tutorials, but I do not have a list. - Apple's official documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html might be difficult to read if you are a Core Data beginner, but at some point you should read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already fetched the User object then simply use `user.picture` to access the picture object. Or `user.picture.pictureName` to access an attribute.

To create the picture in Core Data you MUST use

```
UserPicture *userPicture = = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserPicture" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
userPicture.pictureName = @"picture name";
```

To set the users picture once you have created it use

```
user.picture = userPicture;
```

To save anything you create use

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![managedObjectcontext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```